# Specify a fallback font for runic characters in Emacs?

Tags: fonts

I want to specify a different font from my default font for runic characters in Emacs.

I tried both:

```
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" '(#16a0 . #16ff) "Junicode:Regular")
```

and

```
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'runic "Junicode:Regular")
```

and neither seemed to work.  The first reports:

```
 (invalid-read-syntax "#")
```

and the latter seems to silently fail.

Comment: The problem Emacs complains about is that you used `#`. Characters in Emacs Lisp are just integers, but there's a special syntax to write them, which starts with `?` and is followed by the printable version of the character. If you wanted to write a hexadecimal representation, then the proper way of doing it is `16#a0` and `16#ff` respectively.

Comment: @wvxvw I get the same error if I use `16#a0` and `16#ff`.

Comment: Sorry, I confused it with Calc, the proper syntax for Emacs Lisp hexadecimal is `#xa0` and `#xff`.

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there (note the `#x` instead of `#`):

```
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" '(#x16a0 . #x16ff) "Junicode:Regular")
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution I found which seems to work is just to install the Emacs `unicode-fonts` package:

https://github.com/rolandwalker/unicode-fonts

Comment: You are allowed to accept your own answer. Doing so lets people know that the question is already answered.

Comment: This ends up working, but isn't exactly an answer to the original question. In the sense that it doesn't (immediately) allow a custom specification of a particular font to a particular range.

Comment: See Clément's answer, which *is* exactly an answer to the original question. You should accept it.